# Lower rental amount found on an ad

Tags: rental-property, deposits, landlord

I paid a deposit on an apartment and a day later I found an ad for my same apartment with a lower monthly rent amount. Can I use a screenshot of that ad to get my monthly rental amount to match the lower rental amount from the ad? The receipt I received when I paid the deposit doesn't list a rental amount. I also didn't sign the lease yet since that happens a month from now on move-in day.

Comment: This is probably more a legal question (see [Law StackExchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/), but check their help pages before asking) than one of personal finance. In any event, you will need to add your country and, if in the USA, which state as laws vary widely.

Comment: Are you sure it is the same apartment?  in some complexes the rent can vary by floor, and building. Some will even charge a different amount depending on the length of the lease.

Comment: If it's on Craigslist, the ad might be from a scammer.  I saw that a **lot** when looking for an apartment.

Comment: This would depend on the landlord, a contract is binding at the price agreed.